# loop and print stars in same line unix command

Tags: bash, unix

Hi I have written a script which has a while loop in it. The script when ran takes time to complete so I planned to add something to show as a loading bar.

Now I have added stars like this:

```
while read line
do
         #MY SCRIPT IS HERE

        echo "*"
done < finalout.txt
```

Now my problem is when I am printing the stars, one star star gets printed per line. like this

```
*
*
*
*
```

How is it possible to show it printing in increasing order so that it looks like a loading bar.

```
***** and increasing with the while loop
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use:

```
echo -n '*'
```

OR

```
printf '*'
```

inside the while loop to print characters in the same line. Outside you can add `echo` to get one final newline as:

```
while read line
do
    echo -n '*'
done < finalout.txt
echo
```

Comment: super anubhava, you are really good at scripting and regex. I follow you most of the times :)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
echo "*"
```

use

```
echo -e "*\c"
```

To suppress the newline.

Comment: You'd need `echo -e "*\c"`